# True or false: Surjective linear transformation proof verification

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Is it true that if $f:V \to W $ is a surjective linear transformation, then the cardinality $|f^{-1} (w_1)| = |f^{-1}(w_2)|$ for all $w_i \in W$? Here $f^{-1}(w) := ${$v \in V | f(v) = w$}. If it is, prove it. If not, provide a counterexample.

I am not sure if my answer is correct.

I think it is false. Let v = span {(1,0,0), (0,1,0)}, w = {(0,0,1)} and T(a,b,c) = (0,0, a+b). Then, it is clear that t is a surjective linear transformation. But $|f^{-1} (0,0,0)| = 1$ and  $|f^{-1} (0,0,1)| = 2$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $f:V\to W$ be a surjective linear map and let $w\in W$. Since $f$ is surjective there exists a $v\in f^{-1}(w)$. It follows that
\begin{align*}
f^{-1}(w)
&= \{u\in V:f(u)=w\} \\
&= \{u\in V:f(u)=f(v)\} \\
&= \{u\in V:f(u-v)=\mathbf0\} \\
&= \{u\in V:u-v\in\ker f\} \\
&= \bigcup_{k\in\ker f}\{u\in V:u-v=k\} \\
&= \bigcup_{k\in\ker f}\{v+k\}
\end{align*}
This tells us that the map $\Phi:\ker f\to f^{-1}(w)$ given by $\Phi(k)=v+k$ is a bijection.